# Erro ao buscar/pesquisar atributo em um vetor

Tags: java, array, orientação-a-objetos, gui

Neste programa consigo *inserir* o objeto tranquilamente em meu vetor com o método (adder), porém após não consigo *buscar* a String "placa" que o usuário digitou... programa sempre mostra "Veiculo não encontrado no sistema!".

Obs: o problema esta no método (searcher).

**Classe: Locadora**

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Locadora{
    public static TCarro[] vetor=new TCarro[50];
    public static void main(String[]args){
        for(int i=0;i<vetor.length;i++){
            vetor[i]=new TCarro();
        }
        menu();
    }
    public static void menu(){
        switch(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("#MENU\n1.INCLUIR\n2.PESQUISAR\n"))){
            case 1:
                adder();
            case 2:
                searcher();
            default:
                break;
        }
        menu();
    }
    public static void adder(){
        for(int i=0;i<vetor.length;i++){
            vetor[i].setPlaca(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira a placa:"));
            vetor[i].setCnh(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira a CNH:")));
            vetor[i].setMarca(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira a marca:"));
            vetor[i].setModelo(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira o modelo:"));
            vetor[i].setLocal(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira locatario:"));
            vetor[i].setSit("DISPONIVEL");
            switch(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("#DESEJA ADICIONAR MAIS?\n1.SIM\n2.NAO\n"))){
                case 2:
                    menu();
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void searcher(){
        String placa=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira a placa:");
        for(int i=0;i<vetor.length;i++){
            if(placa.equals(vetor[i].getPlaca())){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"#DETALHES DO CARRO"+
                                            "\nPLACA:"+vetor[i].getPlaca()+
                                            "\nCNH:"+vetor[i].getCnh()+
                                            "\nMARCA:"+vetor[i].getMarca()+
                                            "\nMODELO:"+vetor[i].getModelo()+
                                            "\nLOCATARIO:"+vetor[i].getLocal()+
                                            "\nSITUACAO:"+vetor[i].getSit()+"\n");
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Veiculo não encontrado no sistema!\n");
    }
}
```

**Classe: TCarro**

```
public class TCarro{
    String placa;
    int CNH;
    String marca;
    String modelo;
    String locatario;
    String situacao;

    public void setPlaca(String placa){
        placa=this.placa;
    }
    public String getPlaca(){
        return placa;
    }
    public void setCnh(int CNH){
        CNH=this.CNH;
    }
    public int getCnh(){
        return CNH;
    }
    public void setMarca(String marca){
        marca=this.marca;
    }
    public String getMarca(){
        return marca;
    }
    public void setModelo(String modelo){
        modelo=this.modelo;
    }
    public String getModelo(){
        return modelo;
    }
    public void setLocal(String local){
        locatario=local;
    }
    public String getLocal(){
        return locatario;
    }
    public void setSit(String sit){
        situacao=sit;
    }
    public String getSit(){
        return situacao;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os setters da tua classe TCarro está errado. Você faz assim placa=this.placa, deve ser assim this.placa = placa. Os outros setters devem ser corrigidos também. O clase TCarro deve ficar da seguinte forma:

```
public class TCarro {
String placa;
int CNH;
String marca;
String modelo;
String locatario;
String situacao;

public void setPlaca(String placa){
    this.placa = placa;
}
public String getPlaca(){
    return placa;
}
public void setCnh(int CNH){
    this.CNH = CNH;
}
public int getCnh(){
    return CNH;
}
public void setMarca(String marca){
    this.marca = marca;
}
public String getMarca(){
    return marca;
}
public void setModelo(String modelo){
    this.modelo = modelo;
}
public String getModelo(){
    return modelo;
}
public void setLocal(String local){
    locatario=local;
}
public String getLocal(){
    return locatario;
}
public void setSit(String sit){
    situacao=sit;
}
public String getSit(){
    return situacao;
}
```

}

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado!
Nem imaginava isso...

Comment: Disponha, marca como resolvido a thread.

Answer (score 0):

Como citado na resposta anterior, a resolução estava em seus getters e setters, e para não ter mais esse problema, tem um jeito fácil de resolver.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Utilizando o Eclipse, ao clicar com o botão direito na sua classe, você terá a opção "Generate Getters and Setters..." e o Eclipse vai criar todos os métodos automáticamente.

Caso esteja usando o NetBeans, se você pressionar Alt + Insert vai abrir uma aba "Gerar" e uma das opções será os Getters and Setters.
Para você deixar sua classe melhor organizada, as duas IDE fazem isso pra você.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vlw pela dica meu amigo!